# list of all/best gems for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've been out of the Ruby world for a while (3 years), but I'm coming back for a project.  I am now overwhelmed by all the gems available.  Is there a list of gems by popularity/best gems?  And where is the current list of all the gems?

Comment: I have created a list of gems for Development Machine in Ruby on Rails
http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2013/04/must-have-gems-for-development-machine-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: Best gems? [Those by Yusuke Endoh, without doubt](https://github.com/mame).

Comment: Take a look to [Awesome Ruby](http://awesome-ruby.com), a categorized community-driven collection of well-known Ruby resources.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I don't know about "best," but if you want to see a list of commonly used gems for various purposes, I've found [The Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/) to be a great resource.  The rankings are determined by counting up the number of forks and watchers of various github projects, so I'd view it less as "this is what I should be using," and more as "these are some things I should check out."  At the very least, they're all likely to be under active development and fairly up to date, and it's very useful to see groups of gems broken down by category.

To get a list of all gems from a particular source, you can use `gem list --remote`, as August points out.  Rubyforge (which is your default source) and github are definitely the two most-used.

Comment: More useful answers were left [here to this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/822980/181638) before it also got closed.

Comment: There is also this: http://bestgems.org/

Answer (score 5):

Ruby gems is a package manager for ruby projects. There is no such thing as "best" gems. Perhaps most used, but not "best".

For a list of all the gems on rubygems.org, try `gem list --remote`. You can also try `gem list --remote --source=http://gems.github.com/`, since github is a popular gem distribution source as well.

Answer (score 5):

Gemcutter is an alternative source for deploying Ruby gems, and it maintains some stats as to which are the most downloaded gems (which hints at popularity).

http://gemcutter.org/stats

Unfortunately it doesn't maintain much more than a top 10 on the stats page, which is flooded with Rails dependencies. However if you search for specific gems you can see the download stats quite clearly to gauge popularity.

Comment: Gemcutter is now [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org), the dominant source for rubygems. Stats page is still pretty much the same though.