# what are useful gem that are widely use in Ruby on Rails Web Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

what are useful Gems that are widely use in Ruby on Rails Web Application.
I am asking for learning purpose.
Please Help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [list of all/best gems for Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251664/list-of-all-best-gems-for-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/, it helped me many times to find the right gem for a job.